# Showing content from database only once with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to show images with a specific subject on the screen. I have 5 images with the same subject and it only shows one image. If I change the subject of the image in the database, the next image with the subject I try to call appears.

```
function selectSubject($subject){
        $showSubject = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM images WHERE subject = '$subject'");
        while($showSubject = mysql_fetch_array($showSubject)){
                $source_subject_trees = $showSubject['name'];
                echo "<img class=\"subject_images\" src='img/$source_subject_bomen'></>";
        }
    };
```

Comment: You're using the same variable for both the result of the query, and for the return value of `mysql_fetch_array`. Rename one of them, and you should be fine - at the moment, the database result set in `$showSubject` is being over-written by the first record, and ending the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_query()` returns a result handle. You then stomp all over that handle by re-assigning to it within your while() loop:

```
$showSubject = mysql_query(...);

while($showSubject = msyql_fetch_array($showSubject)) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^---here
```

`mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array  of one row's data. Since you're assigning to the **SAME** variable as you stored the actual query result handle, you destroy the result handle... and end up being unable to fetch any more data, because the handle's gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `mysql_query` you can use `GROUP BY subject` to get only distinct result
2. In `mysql_query` you can use `DISTINCT(name)` to get distinct result on selection time

Any of aboue mention option to get as per your valid result.